# How to connect Node js with Magento using Rest API

Tags: javascript, magento2

I am new to Magento and NodeJs. Can anyone please help to make connection between NodeJS application and Magento2 Rest APIs. It will be really great if anyone can provide me step by step procedure for the same.. thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

To make connection between NodeJS application and Magento 2 Rest API you can use module available here https://github.com/DivanteLtd/magento2-rest-client